# MySql select group by count(*) union into delimited string?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, union, csv

How could i produce a comma & semicolon delimited string from this table

Result table with 3 fields

```
GameId(key)  PlayerId(key)  Rank
1            1              1
1            2              2
1            3              3
1            4              4
1            5              5
2            1              2
2            2              3
2            3              1
2            4              5
2            5              4
```

The result i need is close to something like this sql

```
SELECT PlayerId, count(*) as R1 from Result where Rank = 1
group by PlayerId
union
SELECT PlayerId, count(*) as R2 from Result where Rank < 5
group by PlayerId
```

The delimited string should look like 1,5,8;2,3,7;
which is PlayerId,R1,R2;

Comment: What are R1 and R2 supposed to indicate? I'm trying to wrap my head around what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your current example SQL doesn't appear to give anything that relates to what you want the output to look like. For example for plater id 1 R1 will be 1 and R2 will be 2, while for player id 2 R1 doesn't exist while R2 is 2.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question were not clear enough. Anyway, eggyal got it right for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', PlayerId, R1, R2) SEPARATOR ';') FROM (
  SELECT   PlayerId, SUM(Rank=1) R1, SUM(Rank<5) R2
  FROM     Result
  GROUP BY PlayerId
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8661/2/0).

Comment: Absolutely what i wanted. Thank you!